# Subir página de wordpress en servidor no actualiza cambios en el tema

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme

Tengo un inconveniente en wordpress, en mi localhost he cargado un tema y luego lo reemplacé.

A este segundo tema lo personalicé, le coloqué imagenes, información, etc, ahora cuando lo subo al servidor gratuito donde estoy haciendo las pruebas no me carga el tema, me carga el tema anterior, he actualizado la base de datos y todo.

Que puede ser?

Comment: Por favor añade los cambios que has realizado en la BBDD y como has realizado el proceso, también estaría bien conocer el tema que estas usando y las versiones de PHP, MySQL, Wordpress...etc

Comment: El tema se llama Zerif Lite, php en mi local 5.6.30, 10.1.21-MariaDB, Wordpress 4.8, y en el servidor de pruebas php 7.0.8, 10.1.20-MariaDB

Answer (score 0):

Podrías adjuntar alguna imagen para ver el tema que tenes en Localhost y el tema que tenes en el servidor?

Subiste la carpeta del tema personalizado? en todo caso, probaste exportar el XML?

Comment: Creo que esto no es una respuesta al problema del usuario, es un comentario que va a permitir clarificar la pregunta. Quizás deberías ponerlo en un comentario y borrar la respuesta.

Comment: @EmilioPlatzer Gracias, soy nuevo en esta red, y mi intención es ayudar con Wordpress. ¿Podrías decirme donde puedo encontrar ayuda para responder correctamente?. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Me refería a esto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer De todos modos lo mío era una opinión. Lo más importante lo hiciste bien: tratar de ayudar, ponerle ganas, ser claro. Mi comentario era menor (sobre el lugar donde conviene poner ese tipo de repreguntas).